# After upgrade Jenkins, the email cannot show environment variable when build failure

Tags: jenkins

Upgrade the Jenkins to 2.278, after upgrade, if build
error, the content of email show:

```
$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS:

Check console output at $BUILD_URL to view the results.
```

It will not display the real value, but I can find them
in the '*Environment variables* ', like:

```
BUILD_CAUSE MANUALTRIGGER
BUILD_CAUSE_MANUALTRIGGER   true
BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME  #35
BUILD_ID    35
BUILD_NUMBER    35
BUILD_TAG   jenkins-trigger-test-35
BUILD_URL   http://192.168.10.99:8080/job/trigger-test/35/
...
```

then I upgrade the Email Extension Plugin to 2.80, but
still with no lucky.

Does anyone know what's wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just for anyone who encounter this problem, I resolved by reinstall the jenkins. Backup the orignal /var/lib/jenkins/ and uninstall the old one, reinstall it again from beginning. then move back the backup-ed /var/lib/jenkins

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to update Token Macro to 2.14 or later